# In a Spring Boot application is a Bean Factory/Application context ever explicitly used?

Tags: spring-boot

I am fairly new to Spring Boot and it is my sense from looking at sample applications that if a Bean Factory is ever used, it is used "under the covers" by Spring Boot. Or are there cases when using Spring Boot that you would in fact want to explicitly obtain a bean using the Bean Factory?

Answer (score 0):

Every once in a while, I access Spring `ApplicationContext` from a bean that I initialize with `new` (basically a non-Spring managed bean) as follows:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac)
            throws BeansException {
        context = ac;
    }
}
```

and in wherever I need it:

```
SomeBean someBean = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("testBean", TestBean.class);
```

This is because:

1. I have to access a singleton (say, a `@Service` or a `@Repository`) from a bean I initialize (`new`) and I cannot make my bean Spring managed for that case. (so no `@Autowired`).
2. I don't want to introduce `@Configurable` to the project because it brings in AspectJ, which might be overkill to introduce for this simple case.